characterization of signed distance function on plane
Let $S$ be a simple closed curve on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The original definition of the signed distance function for $S$ is
$$
f(p)= \begin{cases}
d(p, S) & \text{if } p \text{ is outside } S \\
0 & \text{if } p \text{ is on } S \\
-d(p, S) & \text{if } p \text{ is inside } S
\end{cases}
$$
where $d(p, S)$ denotes the Euclidean distance from the point $p$ to the curve $S$. A nice property of the signed distance function is that it solves the Eikonal equation with zero boundary value at the curve. By noticing that gradient is the direction of greatest ascent, we may conjecture that
Conjecture:
A function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a signed distance function for $S=f^{-1}(0)$ if and only if it satisfies $|\nabla f| = 1$ and
\begin{equation}\label{sdf characterization}
\forall p \in \mathbb{R}^2, \quad 0 = f(p - f(p) \nabla f(p))
\end{equation}
The intuition is that when starting at point $p$, travelling with time $t=f(p)$ in direction of $\nabla f(p)$, we should be able to hit the zero level set, where $f$ is valued to be zero. I tried to do this several times but failed to see how to show it or gave counterexamples. On the other hand, I am thinking a possible deficiency of this characterization: although negative gradient is the direction of largest descent, it is only for the point $p$. After $p$ travels to the next point $p_1$ along the negative gradient, the gradient on $p_1$ changes and we need to adjust the direction. That is, it seems that $0 = f(p-f(p)\nabla f(p))$ assumes that our gradient vector field is radial (all the directions line up and are outward-pointing). Thus, I think any function with gradient vector field failing to be radial can server as counterexamples.

Lemma 1:
Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, $K\subseteq M$, and $f:K\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function whose restriction to some open set $W\subseteq K$ is a smooth local distance function. For every admissible curve (i.e. piece-wise smooth curve) $\sigma:[a_0,b_0]\to K$ such that $\sigma ((a_0,b_0))\subseteq W$, we have
$$
L_g(\sigma) \ge |f(\sigma(b_0)) - f(\sigma(a_0))|
$$
where $L_g(\sigma)$ is the length of the curve $\sigma$
proof:
See [LeeRM] Lemma 6.33.
Theorem [Characterization of Signed Distance Function]
A function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a signed distance function if and only if it satisfies $|\nabla f| = 1$ and
\begin{equation}\label{closest point function}
\forall p \in \mathbb{R}^2, \quad 0 = f(p - f(p) \nabla f(p))
\end{equation}
This is called \textbf{closest point function} in \cite{Marschner}.
proof:
$\Longrightarrow$ is standard. We show the other direction. Suppose we are given (\refeq{closest point function}), then there is a point $q \in S:=f^{-1}(0)$ such that
\begin{equation}
(*):\qquad p-f(p) \nabla f(p)=q \Longrightarrow p-q=f(p) \nabla f(p) \Longrightarrow\|p-q\|=|f(p)|
\end{equation}
where the last step is due to $|\nabla f(p)| = 1$.
We didn't use the full power of $|\nabla f(p)|$ yet. Suppose $r\in S$ is the closest point to $p$, i.e., $r = \mathrm{argmin}_{x\in S}d(x,p)$ (note that infimum can be reached via applying extreme value theorem with compactness of $S$). Then we want to show that $q=r$. Let $\sigma: [0,1] \to \Omega$ be a curve defined by $t\mapsto p+t(r-p)$. Now apply Lemma 1 to $\sigma$ with $K=W=\Omega$. Then
\begin{equation}
(**):\qquad\|r-p\|=L(\sigma)\ge |f(\sigma(1))-f(\sigma(0))|=|f(r)-f(p)|=|f(p)|
\end{equation}
Now (*) combined with (**) imply that
$$
|r-p|\ge |q-p|
$$
Thus, $q$ cannot be any point other than the closest point $r$.
proof [original proof in the paper]:
We first show that Eikonality implies that $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz, i.e., $|f(x)-f(y)|\le \|x-y\|$.
For any two points $x$ and $y$, the mean value theorem for differentiable functions tells us that there exists a point $c$ on the line segment joining $x$ and $y$ such that:
$$
u(y)-u(x)=\nabla u(c) \cdot(y-x) \text {. }
$$
Taking the absolute value and using the fact that $\|\nabla u(c)\|=1$, we get:
$$
|u(y)-u(x)|=|\nabla u(c) \cdot(y-x)| \leq\|\nabla u(c)\| \cdot\|y-x\|=\|y-x\|
$$
Then with the same contradiction proof, we start assuming that $r$ is the nearest and $q$ is given from (\refeq{closest point function}), and we still have (*) and
$|f(p)|=\|p-q\|>\|r-p\|$. But $f$ being $1$-Lipschitz says that $|f(p)-f(r)|<\|p-r\|$, meaning that $|f(p)-f(r)|<|f(p)|$ and thus necessarily $|f(r)|>0$, which is impossible since $r \in S$.
\bibitem{LeeRM} Lee, John M. {\em Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds}, Springer Cham, vol. 2, 2018.
\bibitem{Marschner} Marschner, Zoë, et al. "Constructive Solid Geometry on Neural Signed Distance Fields." {\em SIGGRAPH Asia 2023 Conference Papers}, 2023.
